# «...В одной из своих ипостасей...» — нужно ли выделять запятыми?

Tags: пунктуация

«Шива, в одной из своих ипостасей, предстаёт как бог отрёкшихся и может являться своим преданным в видениях как аскет со спутанными волосами». Нужно ли выделять запятыми фразу «в одной из своих ипостасей»? И какую синтаксическую функцию данная фраза выполняет в предложении?